# how to know which online databases are available to connect

Tags: android, database

I'm building a *client server android app*  that has to do with stores and I want (when the user is close to 2 or 3 stores with their database online) my app **to understand that he can connect to one of these stores' databases** and list them to the screen. (just what is happenning with the available wifis when we want to connect to the internet)

How can I achieve that?
I hope I made clear what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong. You are writing an app, that can access data from a server, where the server/database belongs to a store?

If my understanding of your question is correct, do the following:

- Create a connection broadcast that listens for changes in connectivity
- Create a GPS Manager that compares the current location to that based off the location from the stores
- If in range of one or more stores AND a connection is available, query the server via a restfull request, on the server side, fire a query, see if you get any result(I don't know if there exists a specific query to check for database connectivity from server-side code to database) If you get a result, the database is available, send a result back from the server to the client, and list the database/store as available.

I personally would use JSON for the requests from client <-> server. As it is lightweight and easy to use.

For writing a broadcaster: [BraodcastReciever](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

Example:

```
private Context _context;
private State _state;
private boolean _listening;
private String _reason;
private boolean _isFailOver;

private NetworkInfo _networkInfo;

private NetworkInfo _otherNetworkInfo;
private ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver _receiver;
/**
 * The broadcast that listens to connectivity changes(wifi, mobile network etc)
 * */
private class ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    /**
     * Called when connectivity state changes
     * 
     * @param Context the context
     * @param Intent the intent containing the information about the change
     * */
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if(!action.equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION) || _listening == false) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onReceived() called with " + _state.toString() + " and " + intent);
            return;
        }

        boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);

        //Set the state according to current connectivity.
        if(noConnectivity) {
            _state = State.NOT_CONNECTED;
        } else {
            _state = State.CONNECTED;
        }

        //If current state is CONNECTED. Start background services, otherwise stop services.
        switch(_state) {
        case CONNECTED:
            //Do stuff when connected
            break;
        case NOT_CONNECTED:
            //Do stuff if not connected
            break;
        }

        _networkInfo = (NetworkInfo)intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
        _otherNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo)intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_OTHER_NETWORK_INFO);

        _reason = intent.getStringExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_REASON);
        _isFailOver = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_IS_FAILOVER, false);

        Log.d(TAG, "onRecieve(): _networkInfo= " + _networkInfo + " _otherNetworkInfo= " + (_otherNetworkInfo == null ? "[none]" : _otherNetworkInfo + 
                " noConn= " + noConnectivity) + " _state= " + _state.toString());
    }
};
```

I am not posting the entire code. I wrote a wrapper around the ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver. But with the given code you should be able to get far enough.Note that in the code State is an **enum** containing 3 values: CONNECTED, NOT_CONNECTED, UNKNOWN

As for the GPS manager:

```
    /**
 * <h1>GPSManager</h1>
 * 
 * <p>
 * Manager for GPS tracking.
 * Able to enable and disable GPS tracking for the application.
 * </p>
 * */
public class GPSManager {
    public static final String TAG = "LocationFinder";
    private double _lat;
    private double _lon;
    private float _accuracy;
    private Context _context;
    private LocationManager _locManager;
    private LocationListener _locListener;

    private static GPSManager _instance;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     * 
     * @param context The context of the caller.
     * */
    private GPSManager(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
        this._locListener = new LocationTracker();
    }

    /**
     * GPSManager is singleton. Retrieve the shared instance.
     * 
     * @param context The context of the caller.
     * @return GPSManager An instance of the GPSManager class.
     * */
    public static synchronized GPSManager getInstance(Context context) {
        if(_instance == null) {
            _instance = new GPSManager(context);
        }
        return _instance;
    }

    /**
     * Start tracking GPS locations.
     * */
    public void startGpsTracking() {
        _locManager = (LocationManager)_context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        _locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
                0, 0, _locListener);
    }

    /**
     * Stop tracking GPS locations.
     * */
    public void stopGpsTracking() {
        _locManager.removeUpdates(_locListener);
        _locManager = null;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the latitude from the GPSManager.
     * 
     * @return double The latitude.
     * */
    public double getLatitude() {
        return _lat;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the longitude from the GPSManager.
     * 
     * @return double The longitude.
     * */
    public double getLongitude() {
        return _lon;
    }

    /**
     * Check if the GPSManager has a fix on a location.
     * 
     * @return boolean True if GPSManager has a fix, otherwise false.
     * */
    public boolean hasFix() {
        if(_lat != 0 && _lon != 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the accuracy of the fix.
     * 
     * @return float The accuracy.
     * */
    public float getAccuracy() {
        return _accuracy;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the last known location.
     * 
     * @return Location The last known location.
     * */
    public Location getLastLocation() {
        return _locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }

    /**
     * <h1>LocationTracker</h1>
     * 
     * <p>Tracks the location for the GPSManager.</p>
     * */
    private class LocationTracker implements LocationListener {
        /** (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.location.LocationListener#onLocationChanged(android.location.Location)
         */
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {      
            _lat = location.getLatitude();
            _lon = location.getLongitude();
            _accuracy = location.getAccuracy();
        }

        /** (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.location.LocationListener#onProviderDisabled(java.lang.String)
         */
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Gps Disabled");     
        }

        /** (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.location.LocationListener#onProviderEnabled(java.lang.String)
         */
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Gps Enabled");  
        }

        /** (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.location.LocationListener#onStatusChanged(java.lang.String, int, android.os.Bundle)
         */
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {};
    };
}
```

Expand this with your own needs. Most code in the gps manager is self explanatory.

And for the restfull stuff, theres so many different approaches, you will have to look that up yourself.

As answer to your comment, I will show you my implementation of the webrequest. 
I personally use apache-mime4j-0.6.jar AND httpmime-4.0.1.jar.

```
WebService _service = new WebService();
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        try {
            MultipartEntity multipart = new MultipartEntity();
            multipart.addPart("username", new StringBody(_inputName));
            multipart.addPart("password", new StringBody(_inputPass));

            _service.post(QfConfig.RESTFUL_LOGIN_URL, multipart);

            long response = _service.getLongResponse();

            if(response != 0) {
                _pgUserId = response;
                _onlineValidated = true;
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I don't know wether you want to POST or GET. The above example uses POST.
I create a MultipartEntity, and add 2 parts to it. The multipart will be send across to the server as a form where the name of the POST value is username, and the VALUE of the post where the name is username is new StringBody(_inputName).

For the post section in my WebService class:

```
public void post(String url, MultipartEntity postData) {
    HttpClient client = null;
    HttpPost post = null;
    HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
    HttpEntity entity = null;
    InputStream _inStream = null;

    try {
        client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        post = new HttpPost();
        URI uri = URI.create(url);
        post.setURI(uri);
        post.setEntity(postData);
        //Execute the HttpPost request and store the response in httpResponse.
        httpResponse = client.execute(post);
        //Set the response code from the request's responst.
        setResponseCode(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        //Retrieve the entity from the response.
        entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        if(entity != null) {
            //Retrieve the content from the entity.
            _inStream = entity.getContent();
            //Convert the InputStream to String and set the String response to the returned value.
            setStringResponse(IOUtility.convertStreamToString(_inStream));
            //Close the InputStream.
            Log.d(TAG, getStringResponse());
        }   

        //try to create a numeric value of the response result and store it if so
        if(GeneralUtil.isNumeric(getStringResponse())) {
            setLongResponse(Long.parseLong(getStringResponse()));
        }

        Log.d(TAG, httpResponse.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        setResponseCode(0);
        setLongResponse(0);
        setStringResponse("");
    } finally {
        try {
            _inStream.close();
        } catch (Exception ignore) {}
    }
}
```

I work via https, which is more complex so I left those things out. What I do here is, create a new httpClient and HttpPost, set the URI if the post, add the multipart data to post.setEntity() and then execute the request and save the response in a HttpResponse object.

I then retrieve the entity and save it as HttpEntity, as to where I get the response content out of. Which can be a JSON string, a number, whatever you want basically.
I then set some methods which helps me retrieve the results easily by getters and setters.

For a HttpGet its even easier, you only need to pass an url , instead of a HttpPost object you create an HttpGet object, pass it the url, _client.execute([HttpGet object]) and retrieve the result the same way.

In the php script, you can literally just use $_POST['username'] which would give the value of username that u set in StringBody in the above code.

With a get, I would advise sending an url(with or without params, and then send back a JSON string as result to the get request.

Let me know if you need more help. I think this is as far as I can go though. I can't show the php side cause I use a self designed framework.

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I want to do.. i ll try.. as for the client-server communication I have tried this example but it doesn't work  [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

Comment: @mprog I can't give direct code with instructions, but the link you gave is a bit complex, I suggest you search something along the lines of: "android restful" and start with something simple like a login page. If you can do this, you can do any other operation. Cause a login generally requires the same connection you need just with different results. I hope this will help you further. Goodluck! If you have more questions, let me know. There are alot of online examples for restful requests though.

Comment: i have tried many of these examples you mentioned but no one worked..the program usually stops at executing the http post/get.. the only example that works for me is [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/). do i have to add any jar file or something? (I' m running wamp (port 80 @ httpd.conf file) and from eclipse i define the connection url as http://10.0.2.2/something.php if you have in mind 1. 2. 3. things from your experience concerning the connection failure, pls mention, thnx